# Instagram - Get Direct Message

Tags: api, instagram, message

I'm writting a new post, because all of topics that was related with getting Instagram Direct message via API are a little bit old.
Do anyone knows if there is a possibility of GET Direct Messages via API or in some programatically way?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it doesn't look like you can. The [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview) docs don't mention direct messages at all. The [old Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) never had this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the Component InstagramApiSharp, it contains this functionnality. There are  some actions that you can built for the direct message with it.

Comment: Some examples will be more helpful.